# Classifying a sample in to cluster by distance between its centroid

Tags: python, machine-learning, k-means, centroid

I have data that are labelled it into two clusters (eg: postive, negative). I will have new sample data, and based on the shortest distance from the centroids of two clusters I want to classify the new sample as positive or negative. For those i could find examples of [KMeans](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/kmeans-clustering-centroid/). My sample data of positive looks like this

```
x1 = np.array([ 0.170755, ......      0.313704,  0.10206 ]) # 56 dimensions
x2 = np.array([-0.371852, ......      0.255809,  0.475981]) 
.... x28
```

Now I am trying to calculate centroid of my cluster using the example mentioned in the above mentioned link.

```
X = np.array(list(zip(x,x2,x3, ..., x28))).reshape(len(x1),28)
kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters=1).fit(X)
```

As I know this data belongs to one cluster i gave the value of n_clusters=1, but when I am trying to print the value of centroid `kmeans_model.cluster_centers_` it gives me array like `[[0.02490224, 0.12898346]]`, but I am expecting a array in same dimension as x1. Am I calculating the centroid correctly or did my basic understanding go wrong ?

In that case how will be able to calculate the distance between that centroid and new sample which is similar to x1 ?

Comment: what is the result of `X.shape`?

Comment: If your data are labeled, this is a supervised classification problem and there is no reason to use k-means. You can compute the centroid for a set of vectors as `np.mean(np.array([x1, x2,..., xN], axis=0)`.

Comment: Typo in my comment above. It should be `np.mean([x1, x2,..., xN], axis=0)`

Comment: yeah @bogatron , I got it. Thank you for your help.